# SQL Allow user to run Read Only Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have stored procedures in database SQL Server 2016. Say TestDB.

Is there method allowing users to execute only Read-only stored procedures (No write insert/update stored procedures)? The way everything is setup in our legacy system, schemas are not being utilized to separate read access queries. Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you could come is by putting them into a specific role, and granting that role explicit execute access on just those stored procedures. But you would have to identify all of those stored procedures manually.

Even if a procedure were somehow marked in the metadata as "this procedure doesn't write," the permissions system has no way to say "only do things with read-only objects."